# video in format .dwz to other formats

Tags: video, video-processing, video-encoding, codec

how I can convert a video  .dwz   a to format comertial(avi,mp4 etc) or how I can watch it?.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: This question belongs on super user. move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.dwz (as a video format) is a "Corel DVD MovieFactory project file"

You could try the trial version [here](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1173965700889#tabview=tab0)
Or you could try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and use this [guide](http://wiki.videolan.org/IPod_Video_Conversion_Guide)

However most video "project" files do not contain the actual raw video, but the information on the "project" (i.e. transitions, edits, etc)